# Split file and invoke commands by passing each of the parts via stdin without temp files

Tags: linux, shell

Example file:

```
abc
def
%separator
eee
fff
%separator
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Is it possible to split this file into the logical parts, i.e.:

part 1:

```
abc
def
```

part 2:

```
eee
fff
```

part 3:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

then invoke some command (say `wc -l`) on each of these parts without creating temporary files? What I'm looking for is something like `xargs` that will not inline arguments, but push them through stdin instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such a tool. I came up with the following script. Adjust it to your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

sprtr='%separator'
cmmnd='wc -l'

set -o pipefail

while ! sed -n "/^${sprtr}$/q1;p" | $cmmnd ; do
 :
done
```

It goes like this:

1. `sed` reads from `stdin` until it finds a given separator or EOF, then it quits.
2. The chosen command receives appropriate fragment from `sed`.
3. Unless `$cmmnd` fails, `set -o pipefail`, `!` and `q1` collaborate, so when `$sprtr` is found the entire pipe returns exit status `0`. This executes the (empty) code between `do` and `done`, then loops, so `sed` is run again in order to serve the next fragment.
4. If `$cmmnd` fails or if `$sprtr` is not found (EOF reached), the entire pipe returns nonzero exit status. This makes the script leave the `while` loop.

Some pitfalls:

- You cannot use any separator literally and thoughtlessly. Some values of `$sprtr` will break `sed` command or change its behavior if you don't escape characters special to its syntax. Examples: `/`, `/q; /`.
- `set -o pipefail` works in Bash 3 and above, I think. The alternative (but not quite equivalent) is `mispipe` from `moreutils`.
- Your `sed` needs to understand `q1` (this quits `sed` with exit code `1`).

I admit there's not much elegance in this solution.

Comment: Thanks Kamil - interesting! I agree it's a bit of a stretch of a solution, but some nice things there that I did not consider and they might be handy down the road, so +1 from me for the effort!